# Remove duplicates from lists within a vector in R

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have a vector of lists like the following sample:

```
library(tidyverse)

z <- tribble(
  ~x,
  c(10, 10, 64),
  c(22, 22),
  c(5, 9, 9),
  c(55, 55),
  c(76, 65)
)
```

I'm trying to reduce each list to include only cases with unique values. Here's the output I'm looking for:

```
y <- tribble(
  ~x,
  c(10, 64),
  c(22),
  c(5, 9),
  c(55),
  c(76, 65)
)
```

Of course I can't post the actual output and have to write it out as a new data set for this example because it looks like this otherwise:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  x        
  <list>   
1 <dbl [3]>
2 <dbl [2]>
3 <dbl [3]>
4 <dbl [2]>
5 <dbl [2]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `map` and apply `unique`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
z %>% 
   mutate(x = map(x, unique))
```

---

In `base R`, it would be

```
z$x <- lapply(z$x, unique)
```